# google Subscription Purchase order id format

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

I have application in android play with Subscription Purchase, sometimes I receive order id for Subscription Purchase like 6547967659017925362.8852561051676274, with token, when I check the  token with google Subscription Purchase api the result the token is Invalid Value, most of Subscription Purchase order id like GPA.3379-****-****-***** format, but sometime receive another format.
 What is this format  "6547967659017925362.8852561051676274" and why do I receive it like this?

Comment: Exactly same problem here. I know only that  "6547967659017925362.8852561051676274" is the old Order ID format, but it is unclear can e.g. some old devices generate those old ids still. I couldn't find those Order IDs either from the Google Play Console under "Order management". I am  now wondering should I reject those subscriptions or can they still be valid?

Comment: i also have similar problem any solution?